# How does scope affect global and local structures of the same name?

Tags: c

I have declared two different structures with same name foo, as one of them is declared as globally, and can be easily accessible by any function in program. But I have this second struct in main, which is  locally declared.

Worst comes worst I need to access both of them in main? I did it by declaring struct variable with different names. But now the problem is I need to check size of structures... How should I get the size of local struct not a global one?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct foo {
    char arr1[200];
    int x_val;
    int y_val;
    float result;
};
struct foo globe_foo;

int main()
{
    struct foo {
        char c;
        char arr[20];
        int x;
    }; 

    struct foo my_foo;
    globe_foo.x_val = 20;
    printf("Globe foo x_val: %d\n",globe_foo.x_val);
    printf("Size of struct foo is: %d\n",sizeof(struct foo));

    //how to check size of global decleared stuct foo? 
    printf("Size of struct foo is: %d\n",sizeof(struct foo));           
    system("pause"); 
    return 0;                        
}
```

Comment: why don't you just define them with different names?

Comment: Try `sizeof(globe_foo)`.

Comment: Yes i can ....but trying to understand C

Comment: @studyembedded Rule of thumb is that local declarations hide global ones. Use different names and don't complicate yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Variables within block scope whose name is same as the global scope hides the global identifier

[ISO C9899 in 6.2.1](http://busybox.net/~landley/c99-draft.html#6.2.1) says:

> If an identiﬁer designates two different entities in the same name space, the scopes might overlap.  If so, the scope of one entity (the inner scope) will be a strict subset of the scope of the other entity (the outer scope). Within the inner scope, the identiﬁer designates the entity declared in the inner scope; the entity declared in the outer scope is hidden (and not visible) within the inner scope.

So here the global `struct foo` is hidden totally(as if its not there) if you just refer to the typename inside the `main()`.

Suggestions : use different names or use variables with different names for these types or typedef the struct types.

Your `printf("Size of struct foo is: %d\n",sizeof(struct foo));` will give the size of only local struct foo(28 or 25 depends).

Answer (score 1):

Standard C does not provide any way to refer to an identifier (either object name or type name) that is hidden by a local declaration.

In this case, you can see the size of the global `struct foo` by using the size of the object, `sizeof globe_foo`.

GCC (and compilers supporting its extensions) provides a way to refer to the type of an object, `__typeof__`. So, in GCC, you can refer to the type of `globe_foo` with `__typeof__(struct globe_foo)`.

Another option is to give the global type an alias, with `typedef`. If, at file scope, you declare `typedef struct foo foo_t;`, then the type `foo_t` will be visible inside a function even when `struct foo` is hidden.

When printing sizes (values of type `size_t`), you should use a `%zu` specification with `printf`, not `%d`.